# move a django project from "http://ip_address/" to "http://api.domain/

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, digital-ocean

I was developing with just the IP Address, now I'm almost done, and I would move the whole project to "api.domain." I set this in the settings.py `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['api.*domain*.com']` But it's not enough I think. 
I get `404 not found` and it comes from nginx.
I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04). It's the first time that I've to do this by myself. So, I don't have any idea.

Maybe someone had the same problem or knows how to solve it.

**UWSGI Configuration** (/etc/uwsgi/sites/apibackend.ini)

```
[uwsgi]

chdir = /home/chuckaguilar/apibackend/apibackend
home = /home/chuckaguilar/apibackend/apibackendenv
module = apibackend.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/apibackend.sock
chown-socket = chuckaguilar:www-data
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

**UWSGI Configuration** (/etc/uwsgi/sites/apibackend.ini)

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown chuckaguilar:www-data /ru$
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**NGINX Configuration** (/etc/nginx/sites-available/apibackend)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *ip*;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/chuckaguilar/apibackend/apibackend;
        }

        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/apibackend.sock;
        }
}
```

As I said, it works properly, it's just that I would love to have a "normal" Website in "www.domain.com" and the *app api* in "api.domain.com"

When I ping *api.domain.com* it works properly.

Comment: Can you post your NGINX config?

Comment: Can you post a little more information, is this on the same server? is the api.domain.com dns set up correctly? can you post your nginx config file? have you setup wsgi correctly?

Comment: I didn't have an idea what could be relevant information. I'll post the nginx config. I don't know if I've set up wsgi correctly , I just followed that tutorial and saw that everything worked properly and when I make changes, they're made after wsgi restart. And yes, is the same server. Just that I was using it without domain, just for testing and now I would like that the backend endpoints are just throw "api.domain" accesibles.

Comment: there are the specifications. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to have this conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.domain.com;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/chuckaguilar/apibackend/apibackend;
        }

        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/apibackend.sock;
        }
}
```

and then in my settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.domain.com', *ip*, '127.0.0.1']
```